# Probability of an Event A succeeding, if it constantly repeats another Event B when failing, which calls Event A on its' failiure

Tags: probability

Essentially, I have events **A** and **B**. $P(A) = \frac{1}{2}$, and $P(B) =\frac{5}{9}$. Event A is called first, and if it fails, event B is called. If event B fails, event A is called again. How would I go about calculating the exact probability of event A? I know I can approximate it using something along the lines of: $$\sum_{i=0}^n\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{9}\right)^i\cdot\frac{1}{2}$$ But I'm certain there is a much simpler way of arriving at the exact answer (which I happen to know is $\frac{9}{14}$, I just don't know the proper method of calculating it).

Comment: please note $n = \infty$. So you have an infinite geometric series - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series

Answer (score 0):

$x = \frac{1}{2} + \left(\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{4}{9} \times x\right) \implies $

$\frac{14}{18}x = \frac{1}{2} \implies x = \frac{18 \times 1}{14 \times 2}.$

The idea behind the 1st line above, is that if events $A$ and $B$ both fail, you are *right back where you started.*